# Having trouble setting up a multiple case countdown timer in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, timer, countdown

I'm setting up a countdown timer that will count down to two different times a day over the course of a week, so a total of 14 different cases. I've tried a switch statement, and an if-else was recommended to me instead. However, I cannot seem to get my code to work, if anybody could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I Managed to solve it with a switch, but I'm sure it could be cleaner.

```
var curday;
var days;
var hours
var mins
var secs;
var secTime;
var ticker;
var diff;
var nowDate = new Date();



function getSeconds() {
    var wday = nowDate.getDay();
    var chours = nowDate.getHours();
    var cmins = nowDate.getMinutes();
    var dy; //Sunday through Saturday, 0 to 6
    var countertime;
    var curtime;
    var atime;


  switch(nowDate.getDay()) {
  case 0: //Sunday
   if (nowDate.getHours() < 17) {
     dy = 0;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),17,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else {
    dy = 0;
    countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),23,15,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}   
    break;
  case 1:  //Monday
   if (nowDate.getHours() < 10) {
     dy = 1;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),10,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else {
    dy = 1;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),23,15,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}   
    break;
    case 2:  //Tuesday
    if (nowDate.getHours() < 20) {
     dy = 2;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),20,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else {
    dy = 3;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),2,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}
    break;
    case 3:  //Wednesday
    if (nowDate.getHours() < 10 && nowDate.getHours() > 2) {
     dy = 3;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),10,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else if (nowDate.getHours > 10) {
    dy = 3;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),23,15,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}
    break;
    case 4:  //Thursday
    if (nowDate.getHours() < 20) {
     dy = 4;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),20,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else {
    dy = 5;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),2,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}
    break;
    case 5:  //Friday
    if (nowDate.getHours() < 10 && nowDate.getHours() > 2) {
     dy = 5;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),10,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else if (nowDate.getHours > 10) {
    dy = 5;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),23,15,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}
    break;
    case 6:  //Saturday
    if (nowDate.getHours() < 14) {
     dy = 6;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),14,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else {
    dy = 6;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),20,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}
    break;
  default:
     dy = 0;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),0,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}

 curtime = nowDate.getTime(); //current time
 atime = countertime.getTime(); //countdown time

 diff = parseInt((atime - curtime)/1000);
 if (diff > 0) { curday = dy - nowDate.getDay() }
 else { curday = dy - nowDate.getDay() -1 } //after countdown time
 if (curday < 0) { curday += 7; } //already after countdown time, switch to next week
 if (diff <= 0) { diff += (86400 * 7) }
 startTimer (diff);
}

function startTimer(secs) {
 secTime = parseInt(secs);
 ticker = setInterval("tick()",1000);
 tick(); //initial count display
}

function tick() {
 secs = secTime;
 if (secs>0) {
  secTime--;
 }
 else {
  clearInterval(ticker);
  getSeconds(); //start over
 }

 days = Math.floor(secs/86400);
 secs %= 86400;
 hours= Math.floor(secs/3600);
 secs %= 3600;
 mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
 secs %= 60;
```

Comment: You're using an assignment inside an if condition which obviously won't work. First change this `if (nowDate.getDay() = 0 && ...` to this `if (nowDate.getDay() === 0 && ...` then try again.

Comment: I tried this, and it fixed one issue at least. Now the timer is starting, but it just starts at 6 days remaining. Should I initialize the variables inside the if statement?

Comment: Yes, another issue with your code is scoping. Some of your variables are declared inside if blocks and sub functions making them impossible to deal with from your global scope (or at least your main function).

Answer (score 0):

```
var curday;
var days;
var hours
var mins
var secs;
var secTime;
var ticker;
var diff;
var nowDate = new Date();



function getSeconds() {
    var wday = nowDate.getDay();
    var chours = nowDate.getHours();
    var cmins = nowDate.getMinutes();
    var dy; //Sunday through Saturday, 0 to 6
    var countertime;
    var curtime;
    var atime;


  switch(nowDate.getDay()) {
  case 0: //Sunday
   if (nowDate.getHours() < 17) {
     dy = 0;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),17,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else {
    dy = 0;
    countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),23,15,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}   
    break;
  case 1:  //Monday
   if (nowDate.getHours() < 10) {
     dy = 1;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),10,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else {
    dy = 1;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),23,15,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}   
    break;
    case 2:  //Tuesday
    if (nowDate.getHours() < 20) {
     dy = 2;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),20,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else {
    dy = 3;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),2,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}
    break;
    case 3:  //Wednesday
    if (nowDate.getHours() < 10 && nowDate.getHours() > 2) {
     dy = 3;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),10,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else if (nowDate.getHours > 10) {
    dy = 3;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),23,15,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}
    break;
    case 4:  //Thursday
    if (nowDate.getHours() < 20) {
     dy = 4;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),20,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else {
    dy = 5;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),2,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}
    break;
    case 5:  //Friday
    if (nowDate.getHours() < 10 && nowDate.getHours() > 2) {
     dy = 5;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),10,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else if (nowDate.getHours > 10) {
    dy = 5;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),23,15,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}
    break;
    case 6:  //Saturday
    if (nowDate.getHours() < 14) {
     dy = 6;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),14,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
} else {
    dy = 6;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),20,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}
    break;
  default:
     dy = 0;
     countertime = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(),nowDate.getMonth(),nowDate.getDate(),0,0,0); //20 out of 24 hours = 8pm
}

 curtime = nowDate.getTime(); //current time
 atime = countertime.getTime(); //countdown time

 diff = parseInt((atime - curtime)/1000);
 if (diff > 0) { curday = dy - nowDate.getDay() }
 else { curday = dy - nowDate.getDay() -1 } //after countdown time
 if (curday < 0) { curday += 7; } //already after countdown time, switch to next week
 if (diff <= 0) { diff += (86400 * 7) }
 startTimer (diff);
}

function startTimer(secs) {
 secTime = parseInt(secs);
 ticker = setInterval("tick()",1000);
 tick(); //initial count display
}

function tick() {
 secs = secTime;
 if (secs>0) {
  secTime--;
 }
 else {
  clearInterval(ticker);
  getSeconds(); //start over
 }

 days = Math.floor(secs/86400);
 secs %= 86400;
 hours= Math.floor(secs/3600);
 secs %= 3600;
 mins = Math.floor(secs/60);
 secs %= 60;
```